# Remove borders without affecting position

Tags: html, css

I set the borders for all my divs, but when I removed borders it affected the positioning I have set.

```css
div {
 border: 1px solid #1bbc9b;
}

#main {
 width: 1020px;
 margin: auto;
}

#navbar {
 height: 95px;
}

#spacing {
 margin: 25px 0px 55px 25px;
 height: 47px;
}

#logo_img {
 margin-right: 12px;
 float: left;
}

#logo_txt {
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#logo_txt span {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: -0.5em;
}

.float_div {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 height: 47px;
}

#float_div_left {
 float: left;
 width: 25%; 
}

#float_div_left a:link, #float_div_left a:hover, #float_div_left a:active, #float_div_left a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

#float_div_right {
 float: right;
 width: 58%; 
}

#nav_menu {
 margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
 list-style: none;
}

#nav_menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 1px;
}

#nav_menu li a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

#nav_menu li a:hover, #nav_menu li a:active {
 background-color: #1bbc9b;
}

#jumbotron {
 height: 453px;
 background-image: url(../images/jumbotron.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#caption {
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 40px;
 width: 585px;
 height: 350px;
}

#we_bb {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 55px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#we_bb span {
 font-weight: bold;
}

#we_bb_1st_p {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

#learn_more {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 45px;
}

#learn_more a {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: white;
 background-color: #1bbc9b;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#down_button_img {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/css_reset.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/style.css" />
  <title>Site</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main">
   <div id="navbar">
    <div id="spacing">
     <div class="float_div" id="float_div_left">
      <a href="index.html">
       <img src="images/b-logo.jpg" id="logo_img" />
       <p id="logo_txt">BAK-ONE <br/>
        <span>One Page Flat Template</span>
       </p>
      </a>
     </div>
     <div class="float_div" id="float_div_right">
      <ul id="nav_menu">
       <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="jumbotron">
    <div id="caption">
     <h1 id="we_bb">We Build <span>Brand</span></h1>
     <p id="we_bb_1st_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
     <p id="learn_more"><a href="#">LEARN MORE</a></p>
     <img id="down_button_img" src="images/down_button.png" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Site with borders
http://i62.tinypic.com/24cgwwi.jpg

Site without borders
http://i60.tinypic.com/1gsjuc.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to @A.B's answer, you can use [outline](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/ui.html#propdef-outline) which will do the same thing but doesn't take up any space like borders do. However, if your design requires the space used by the border, then you will have to change your element sizes or not use this altogether.

Comment: yes outline is an good option also in this case and shaking border's solution too :)

Answer (score 4):

set borders to transparent color.

Transparent border still holds the space for the border you are just hiding it with its color changed that is not visible , so it doesnt effects your positioning.

Removing the borders completing will effect your positioning(the way you initially calculated things) as border also takes space in outer width(full size) of the element

```
div {
    border: 1px solid transparent ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its help, but can you please tell me the reason if its not difficult for you, thanks again!

Comment: See the updated answer.Good to hear that it helped you  My pleasure :)

Comment: See my answer for an alternative that doesn't require you to write potentially multiple counter-border CSS statements.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to do as Twitter Bootstrap does, and set `box-sizing` to `border-box`. This makes border and padding part of the box's sizing dimension. Bootstrap actually does this for the entire document.

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: pink;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.border {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/s3yhLm6p/)**

The advantage to this technique is that you're not writing extra CSS to handle sizing issues.

Comment: plus one for this , @isherwood what size does box-sizing consider for border width? or default. (just to learn)

Comment: It doesn't care what the border is--it uses the outer dimension of the element regardless.